# I am trying to get all ids where name is equal to a certain value

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7

I am trying to get data from two different tables from first table i am getting name and from the second table i want to get the id.But i am getting an error.

Here is my code

```
try {
  $value=$cluster;
  $cohort_query = "select cohort from vu_institutes_details where cluster=$value";
  $cohort=array();
  $queryResult = db_query($cohort_query);

  foreach ($queryResult as $row) {
    $cohort = $row->cohort;

  }
  foreach ($cohort as $value) {
   $cohid="select id from mdl_cohort where name=$value";

   $queryResul = db_query($cohid);

   foreach ($queryResul as $ro) {
     $cohids=array();
     $cohids = $ro->id;
   }

 }
```

But i get error that cohids does not exsist.

Comment: Use JOINS in MySql

Comment: JOIN is much better idea compare to use multiple foreach to fetch data from multiple tables and it will increase speed performance too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my point of view , the query does not return any record.You can define your "$cohids" outside the foreach scope and try to check with num_rows with conditions.

You have one more issue inside the foreach

```
 foreach ($queryResul as $ro) {
     $cohids=array();
     $cohids = $ro->id;
   }
```

Try to use this one

```
foreach ($queryResul as $ro) {
     $cohids=array();
     $cohids[] = $ro->id;
   }
```

Or

```
foreach ($queryResul as $ro) {

         $cohids = $ro->id;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

as you are declaring cohort and cohids as an array then use it like array.:

```
 foreach ($queryResult as $row) {
        $cohort[] = $row->cohort;
 }
```

also:

```
 $cohids[] = $ro->id;
```